# Como desabilitar a função do botão 'voltar' do navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como impedir que o usuário use o botão voltar do navegado com javascript? Tenho uma pagina e quero que ele use o botão da pagina para voltar.

Comment: Olá, Almir. Seja bem-vindo! Ótima iniciativa, mas, para seguir o formato do site, publique como uma pergunta-- algo como "Como desabilitar a função do botão 'voltar' do navegador?" e publique a sua solução como resposta mesmo.

Comment: Legal, mas como que eu formato para ficar com essa aparência de código? Como eu estou logado não tem a caixa de formatação que aparece aqui quando vou perguntar, pra vc deve aparecer.

Comment: Você provavelmente está tentando fazer isso num comentário. Use a caixa de resposta, que fica logo abaixo de "Sua resposta",. Lá tem as ferramentas de formatação. Selecione o código e clique no ícone que se parece com isso: { } .

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava fazendo, agora esta legal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A ideia aqui para bloquear o botão voltar do browser é colocar um #hash na url do navegador impedindo a pagina de voltar e não desabilitar o próprio botão em si. E ainda apresentar uma msg ao usuário dizendo que ele não pode voltar pelo botão do browser.

Funciona em vários navegadores, inclusive o IE.

```js
/**  
 noback v0.0.1 
 library for prevent backbutton 
 Author: Kiko Mesquita: http://twitter.com/kikomesquita 
 Based on stackoverflow 
 * Copyright (c) 2015 @ kikomesquita 
*/ 

(function(window) { 
  'use strict'; 
 
var noback = { 
  
 //globals 
 version: '0.0.1', 
 history_api : typeof history.pushState !== 'undefined', 
  
 init:function(){ 
  window.location.hash = '#no-back'; 
  noback.configure(); 
 }, 
  
 hasChanged:function(){ 
  if (window.location.hash == '#no-back' ){ 
   window.location.hash = '#BLOQUEIO';
   //mostra mensagem que não pode usar o btn volta do browser
   if($( "#msgAviso" ).css('display') =='none'){
    $( "#msgAviso" ).slideToggle("slow");
   }
  } 
 }, 
  
 checkCompat: function(){ 
  if(window.addEventListener) { 
   window.addEventListener("hashchange", noback.hasChanged, false); 
  }else if (window.attachEvent) { 
   window.attachEvent("onhashchange", noback.hasChanged); 
  }else{ 
   window.onhashchange = noback.hasChanged; 
  } 
 }, 
  
 configure: function(){ 
  if ( window.location.hash == '#no-back' ) { 
   if ( this.history_api ){ 
    history.pushState(null, '', '#BLOQUEIO'); 
   }else{  
    window.location.hash = '#BLOQUEIO';
    //mostra mensagem que não pode usar o btn volta do browser
    if($( "#msgAviso" ).css('display') =='none'){
     $( "#msgAviso" ).slideToggle("slow");
    }
   } 
  } 
  noback.checkCompat(); 
  noback.hasChanged(); 
 } 
  
 }; 
  
 // AMD support 
 if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) { 
  define( function() { return noback; } ); 
 }  
 // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like 
 else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) { 
  module.exports = noback; 
 }  
 else { 
  window.noback = noback; 
 } 
 noback.init();
}(window));
```

Caso queira apresentar uma msg na tela pode usa desta forma ou colocar um `alert` no código.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msgAviso" style="display:none;">
    <span><img src="desabilitaBotao.png"></span>
    <span>Não é permitido voltar pelo botão do browser.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Testado e aprovado no Google Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit), SO = MAC OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)

Comment: Utilizei essa solução para fazer o bloqueio, está funcionando corretamente. Porém, temos algumas telas com abas, e para acessar uma aba específica, utilizamos url + '#nome_aba'.
Com isso o js altera a url para #bloqueio e não acessa mais. Como resolver?