# Ignorar registro quando falta informação MySql / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulário de registro em PHP no banco MySQL. Após o preenchimento do *form*, o usuário é redirecionado para a pagina `cad.php` onde diz que o cadastro foi efetuado com sucesso e em 3 segundos ele é redirecionado para pagina de *login*.

O problema é que se o usuário apertar para voltar, o PHP manda registrar novamente só que com dados em branco, ai cria uma linha sem informações.

Pesquisei na internet sobre ignorar registro com dados faltando, ou o *Not Null*, mas não tive sucesso na busca.

Comment: mesmo abrindo uma session se o usuário clicar em voltar ele registraria denovo, queria colocar tipo um "if nome, email... não conter informaçoes, então redirecionar para pagina inicial"

Comment: Meu caro, creio que isso aqui possa te resolver:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115453/como-desabilitar-a-função-do-botão-voltar-do-navegador

Comment: Estranho. Antes de inserir registros no banco vc não verifica se as variáveis estão vazias? Se fizesse isso, jamais um registro vazio seria inserido no banco.

Comment: De outra forma, poderíamos lhe ajudar melhor se vc postasse seus códigos.